# How to regex replace live() function to on() function

Tags: jquery

I would like to know what regex is to be used in order to change

```
$(".delete_package").live("click", function() {
```

into

```
$("body").on("click", ".delete_package", function() {
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem you're actually trying to solve? Regex replacing javascript code is probably not what you need.

Comment: I have a lot of files that contains jquery live() functions. And now because of I'm using jquery1.9 which does not support live() function anymore, therefore I need to replace all live() into on(). Replace it one by one will be wasting a lot of time. So far what I did is I just replace it one by one, but that is not efficient. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to replace them in your editor, not using jQuery. Which editor?

Comment: I am using PhpDesigner

Comment: How many occurrences of `.live()` do you have? If it's not hundreds, why not inspect them manually?

Comment: You can just replace `live` with `on`: `$(".delete_package").on("click", function() {`

Comment: @Jack: More than 500 occurance in a project.

Comment: Or `.live(` with `.on(` might be more precise.

Comment: Antony, that would change the behavior and be quite dangerous, since you haven't included the selector, also, he's asking for a regex to do the replace, not what to replace it with.

Comment: More than 500? That somehow seems like an abuse of `.live()` imho.

Comment: @TonyChong it doesn't look like phpDesigner has a function for that. Can you use a script? Do you have Java or node.js or php available?

Comment: @Kato: I already got the solution posted by plalx. Thanks a lot, you all save my day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about phpDesigner, but you could try a replace with:

regex: `\$\((["'][^"']+["'])\)\.live\((["'][^"']+["'])`

replace: `$(document.body).on($2, $1`

Some regex engines will use the `\` character for backreferences, so `$1` could be `\1`.

Comment: Keep in mind that will only match on `click`, you need to match the event to replace other events properly.

Answer (score 0):

The regex implementation for PHP/PCRE would be:

```
/\$\(\s*?["']([^"']+?)["']\s*?\)\.live\(\s*?["']([^"']+?)["'][^\(]+?\(/$(document.body).on("$2", "$1", function(/g
```

Regex: `\$\(\s*?["']([^"']+?)["']\s*?\)\.live\(\s*?["']([^"']+?)["'][^\(]+?\(`
Replace: `$(document.body).on("$2", "$1", function(`

It will match on anything that that matches `$("*").live(` pattern ignoring spacing differences. The event is also captured and used in the replacement. Has the side benefit of normalizing your javascript if it has weird spacing.

[Regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/yZ1tX6)